# Java HashSet performance

Tags: java, performance, hashset

I understand `HashSet` based on `HashMap`, since they are pretty similar. It makes the code more flexible and minimizes implementation effort. However, one reference variable in the HashSet's `Entry` seem to be unnecessary for me if the class forbids `null` element, therefore the whole Entry makes no point. Despite this fact, an `Entry` takes 24 byte memory / element, whereas a single array with the set's elements would take only 4 byte / element if my figures are correct. (aside from array's header)

**If my argument is correct, does the advantages really overweight this performance hit?**

(if i am wrong, i would learn from it aswell)

Comment: A single array wouldn't be a HashSet. How would you have O(1) contains() with a simple array?

Comment: @JBNizet linear probing (or generally open addressing) works with just a single array. I'm also curious what the design decision was, but I'm not sure if we find the author here to report ;-)

Comment: @JBNizet You can easily implement several types of hash tables in an array , i.e. cuckoo, linear, etc... EDIT: linear doesn't have O(1) contains(), but cuckoo does

Comment: Some libraries implement their Map as an extension of their Set and this would be more efficient IMHO, however this decision was made at least 20 years ago, so while it made sense at the time, it might not be optimal now.

Comment: @PeterLawrey a bit less than 20 years ago, actually. 20 years ago Java 1.1 was not out yet. And HashSet was introduced in 1.2.

Comment: @JBNizet Good point so only ~17 years.

Comment: 17, 20, it's the same order of magnitude :-) Point is, it's been a while.

Comment: Experimental data about memory footprint of different Set implementations in Java: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26369483/648955

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though this question is primarily opinion-based, I'll summarize a few points on the topic:

- `HashSet` appeared in Java 1.2 many years ago. It's hard to guess now the exact reasons for design decisions made at that times, but clearly Java wasn't used for high-loaded applications; performance played less role than simplicity.
- You are right that `HashSet` is suboptimal in its memory consumption. The problem is known, the bug [JDK-6624565](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6624565) is registered, and discussions at [core-libs-dev](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2013-October/021721.html) are held from time to time. But is this a blocker for many real world applications? Probably, no.
- For those uncommon applications where `HashSet` memory usage is unacceptable, there are already good alternatives, like trove [THashSet](http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/javadocs/gnu/trove/set/hash/THashSet.html).
- Note that open addressing algorithms has their disadvantages, e.g. significant performance degradation with load factors close to 1; element removal difficulties. See the [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12020017/3448419).